# Why the windows authentication works on emulator webview but not on device?

Tags: android, windows, authentication, webview

All. I am working on web view based android application, and need to access one URL which has got windows authentication (Negotiate, NTLM) protected.
I did some code and make it work on the emulator.
But unfortunately, It doesn't work on devices.
I tested with Samsung s8 (Android 9.0), Samsung Tab A (Android 8.1)

Below is the code that I tried to integrate a web view on my application.
As I mentioned, it correctly works on the emulator but not on a device

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mWebView = findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

    // Enable Javascript
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webSettings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");

    // REMOTE RESOURCE
     mWebView.loadUrl("https://palmerston.wheelers.co/account/logon");
     mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
}


--> MyWebViewClient
    @Override
    public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view, HttpAuthHandler handler, String host, String realm) {
        String username="123";
        String userpass="123";
        handler.proceed(username, userpass);
    }
```

I wonder if there is any other configuration or what causes authentication stopping on device webview.
Please help me to solve this problem, if you have faced this kind of issue before.
Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? Page do not load or issues in login?

Comment: It calls onReceviedHttpAuthRequest function again and again, even after username and userpass are correct. It is working okay on browsers / android chrome browsers / android emulator.